# MTLTexture's replaceRegion: on different threads

Tags: concurrency, metal

can you confirm please if MTLTexture method:
`- (void)replaceRegion:(MTLRegion)region mipmapLevel:(NSUInteger)level withBytes:(const void *)pixelBytes bytesPerRow:(NSUInteger)bytesPerRow;`
is thread safe? The source texture is created with the same MTLDevice where the render pass runs. I want to update my pre-allocated textures in the synchroneous concurency loop, out of the rendering pass. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexture/1515679-replaceregion
This method runs on the CPU and immediately copies the pixel data into the texture. It doesn't synchronize against any GPU accesses to the texture. For example, if a command buffer includes read or write operations on a given texture, **you must ensure that these operations complete before calling** the replaceRegion:mipmapLevel:slice:withBytes:bytesPerRow:bytesPerImage: method on the given texture. You can use the addCompletedHandler: method, waitUntilCompleted method, or custom semaphores to signal that a command buffer has completed execution.

It is not thread safe.